# C# Search dictionary having List<string> as value

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have declared following dictionary, it can contain more than 10 items :

```
 Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictTestdata = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
        {
            { "k1", new List<string> { "1", "Programmers" }},
            { "k2", new List<string> { "3", "Testers" }},
            { "k3", new List<string> { "", "Designers" }}, 
        };
```

**Query 1:** I need only those items where the 1st list item is empty. Above example, should return  the 'Designers' item only.

**Query 2:** I also want data if all the 1st list items in above dictionary are empty, see declaration below:

```
dictTestdata = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
        {
            { "k1", new List<string> { "", "Programmers" }},
            { "k2", new List<string> { "", "Testers" }},
            { "k3", new List<string> { "", "Designers" }}, 
        };
```

Example 2, should return  the 'Programmers','Testers','Designers' items.
How do I query this dictionary so that it returns required results in Question 1 and 2 ?

Comment: [What have you tired?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com) (Read the article, if you want help on the internet you need to learn how to ask a well formed question.)

Comment: What *is* the first element in the string list? Does it represent how many programmers/testers/... are there?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain , I should have written that. I tried the following, but was stuck at the 3rd line :                                                                             var results = dictSource.Values;
                    var finalr= from i in results 
                           select results.SelectMany(p=>p.

Comment: Yes @khlr, you are right,first element represents no. of programmers/testers .

Comment: @Tanima ok, then why are you storing the no. as strings? I'd rather use an own strongly typed structure.

Comment: Good suggestion @khlr, shall work towards it; However, above questions still remain valid, have accepted Dreamweaver's solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictTestdata = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
        {
            { "k1", new List<string> { "1", "Programmers" }},
            { "k2", new List<string> { "3", "Testers" }},
            { "k3", new List<string> { "", "Designers" }}, 
        };

            var data =   dictTestdata.Values.Where(m => string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.ElementAtOrDefault(0)));
            foreach (List<string> item in data)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.ElementAtOrDefault(1));
            }

            dictTestdata = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
        {
            { "k1", new List<string> { "", "Programmers" }},
            { "k2", new List<string> { "", "Testers" }},
            { "k3", new List<string> { "", "Designers" }}, 
        };
             data = dictTestdata.Values.Where(m => string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.ElementAtOrDefault(0)));
            foreach (List<string> item in data)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.ElementAtOrDefault(1));
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
```

Comment: I would suggest you to use string.IsNullOrWhitespace instead of string.IsNullOrEmpty. Because, string.IsNullOrEmpty might not catch any empty spaces (if available).

Comment: You are right, @VimalanJayaGanesh , shall incorporate so.

Comment: @Dreamweaver or  Vimalan, Is it possible to return the dictionary's key also in above solution ? So, "k3" can be returned?

Comment: use this ->   dictTestdata.Where(x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Value.ElementAtOrDefault(0)));

Comment: @Dreamweaver, I want minimum value in element(0), tried below but failing: var result = dictTestdata.Values.Where(x => x.Min(Convert.ToInt32(x.ElementAt(0))));      So in my 1st example quoted above result returned should be 1. Can you suggest what I am missing?

Comment: I resolved. Used this query-  string  smin = dictSource.Min(pair => pair.Value.ElementAt(0));
                     dictfiltered = dictSource.Where(pair => pair.Value.ElementAt(0) == smin);

Answer (score 2):

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictTestdata = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
        {
            { "k1", new List<string> { "1", "Programmers" }},
            { "k2", new List<string> { "3", "Testers" }},
            { "k3", new List<string> { "", "Designers" }}, 
            { "k4", new List<string> { "", "Designers2" }}, 
        };

var query = from item in dictTestdata
               where String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Value.First())
               select item.Value.Where(v => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(v));

query.SelectMany (q => q, (a, b) => b).Dump();
```

this code returns:

- Designers
- Designers2

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictTestdata = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
            {
                { "k1", new List<string> { "1", "Programmers" }},
                { "k2", new List<string> { "3", "Testers" }},
                { "k3", new List<string> { "", "Designers" }}, 
            };

            var result1 = dictTestdata.Where(kvp => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(kvp.Value[0]))
                  .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);

            dictTestdata = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
            {
                { "k1", new List<string> { "", "Programmers" }},
                { "k2", new List<string> { "", "Testers" }},
                { "k3", new List<string> { "", "Designers" }}, 
            };

            var result2 = dictTestdata.Where(kvp => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(kvp.Value[0]))
                  .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

Comment: Thank you @Vimalan for the very prompt response